# Canonical question for remapping keyboard keys

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical-answer

We have many questions regarding [remapping keyboard keys](https://superuser.com/search?q=remap+keys+is%3Aq+-%5Bmacos%5D-%5Blinux%5D-%5Bubuntu%5D) on Windows. Should we make one of them a canonical question and close the others as dupes?

Comment: Maybe.  Do you have a specific recommendation for which post or posts would make good canonical questions and which would be duplicates of those?

Comment: @fixer1234 I would recommend this one: [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/q/36920/494585). A number of questions have already been closed as duplicates of it.

Comment: I was looking for that question earlier today but didn't find it when I answered another one of these questions earlier today.

Comment: Presumably you'd still allow at least one question per O/S

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll Yes. I was primarily focusing on Windows though